# Create-React-App in production: Routes not found

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, proxy, create-react-app

I have a fullstack app with Create-React-App and Express.js as the backend.

The development setup (CRA running on port 3000) is realized by CRA's proxies so I can forward certain routes directly to the backend (running on port 5000):

```
"proxy": {
    "/auth/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
}
```

For logging out a user I have a corresponding route:

```
app.get('/api/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

And a logout button that points to this route:

```
<a key="logout" href="/api/logout">Logout</a>
```

***In development mode***, running :3000 and :5000, everything works perfectly. Clicking on on the button sets the URL in the browser which calls the route, the proxy forwards and the backend recognizes and handles the request properly    =>   Session killed!

***In production mode***, hosted on Heroku, the route is simply not found and not triggered. In the network tab the server serves the static html file, maybe due to this configuration:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    const path = require('path');
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}
```

If I logout the user ***programmatically***, by calling the same route `onClick`, it works:

```
await axios.get('/api/logout');
```

But why is the simple redirect of the browser with the `<a>` not working in production?

THX!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

app.use(express.static('client/build'));

const path = require('path');
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
}
```

To this:

```
let root = path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build');
app.use(express.static(root));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
if (req.method === 'GET' && req.accepts('html') && !req.is('json') && 
  !req.path.includes('.')) {
     res.sendFile('index.html', { root });
  } else next();
});
```

Maybe this helps: [Configure production environment in a create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662060/configure-production-environment-in-a-create-react-appsyntaxerror-unexpected-t/52178108#52178108)